# Authors can edit all posts, except when an owner is specified?

Tags: posts, user-roles, permissions

I'm trying to do as follows:

- All users can edit all posts from other authors (sort of wiki)
- Some posts have an "owner". When owner is specified only this user can edit the post.

Do you have any suggestions for this kind of permission settings?

Comment: What do you mean by "owner"? Every post has an author so I don't think that is what you mean. You scheme would not work if it were since everything would be "owned".

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it well. 

"Owned" is a flag I will add to my custom post type via custom field (just for some posts). This kind of post has a specified author that will be the only able to edit the post.

All the "non-owned" submitted posts should not be associated to a specific author (maybe all associated with admin or similar) and be editable by everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I got it, just needed some simple logic.

If the post has an "owner" (the only person that can edit the post) I manually set the custom field "owned" to 1 and the author as the one that can edit.

On the edit post page (I'm doing it front-end) I check if "owned" custom field is = 1 and the author is = current user then I show the edit form. If not, I display a message. If the custom field "owned" is = 0, then I display the edit form so everyone can edit.